# Output line numbers parallel to output

Tags: java, count, while-loop, numbers, line

thank you all for looking.

I am a beginner to Java and have been for a few years.
I am not looking for the answer but would like some to tips to finish my query.

I want to output line numbers with my out put of code in netbeans.

I am guessing a while loop would be sufficient.

I would like my output to look like the below example:
I am looking to add line numbers to my output like they are in bold below.

**1**: Enter a line
Some input

**2**: Enter another line

More input

**3**: Enter the last line

The end

The end,More input,Some input

HERE IS my code i would like to add to:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String msg1, msg2, msg3;
System.out.println("Enter a line");
msg1 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter another line");
msg2 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the last line");
msg3 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(msg3 + "," + msg2 + "," + msg1);
```

---

This is what I am guessing i should add, however I may be totally wrong

```
int count = 0;

while (count ??????) {
  count++;
  System.out.println(count + "" + ?????????????()); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice,
regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your homework, but I would answer it anyway

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String msg1, msg2, msg3;
int count = 0;
System.out.println(++count + ": Enter a line");
msg1 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(++count + ": Enter another line");
msg2 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(++count + ": Enter the last line");
msg3 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(msg3 + "," + msg2 + "," + msg1);
```

Comment: Thanks,I did state that I was asking for tips not the solution.I appreciate your time.